# Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000. MSSQL though ODBC from PHP

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, odbc

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure in a ms sql database using the following php:

```
$query = "{CALL dbo.storedProc('functionName', $date, 'id";
$resultSet = odbc_prepare($connection, $query);
odbc_execute($resultSet, array());
odbc_result_all($resultSet);
```

The same stored procedure works fine for a different function, and the results are selected by date like so ($date is @Searchstr):

```
(EventStart >= @Searchstr AND EventStart < DATEADD(DD,1,@Searchstr))
```

However, when I run the code, it errors without giving any specific hints as to what's causing the error. When the query is run in management studio, the results are returned correctly.

```
SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Syntax error or access violation, SQL state 37000 in SQLPrepare in ...
```

What's causing the query to error? Could it be an ODBC bug?

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: The query seems to at least be missing `')}` at the end.

Comment: Whoops, must have missed that with the copy/paste.

Comment: To clarify, it's fixed now. Another triumph for silly mistakes. I can't answer the question for another 7 hours though - low rep.

Comment: Added it as an answer, not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query seems to be missing `')}` at the end.